# How do I trim the following string?

Tags: c#

I have the string: `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get"`.  I want to trim everything from the last slash, so I just remain with `"Get"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the LastIndexOf method to get the position of the last / in the string and pass that into the Substring method as how many characters you want to trim off the string. That should leave you with the Get at the end.

```
[TestMethod]
  public void ShouldResultInGet()
  {
     string url = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get";

     int indexOfLastSlash = url.LastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1; //don't want to include the last /

     Assert.AreEqual( "Get", url.Substring( indexOfLastSlash ) );
  }
```

Comment: Question:  What will happen if it does not find a slash.  Will it just ignore it or will it throw an exception?

Comment: It will return the complete string

Answer (score 9):

```
var s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get";
s = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use String.LastIndexOf to get the last forward slash

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224422.aspx

Answer (score 1):

URI alternative if your using the well formed /Get /Put /Delete etc

```
var uri = new System.Uri("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get");
string top = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int indexOfLastSlash = url.LastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1;

string s = url.Remove(0, indexOfLastSlash);

Assert.AreEqual( "Get", s );
```

this removes all data before & including the last '/'.

works fine here.